# Angular js - Return a string with HTML characters like &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, html, string, angularjs

I made a filter just to add an antislash after a value if another given value is not empty and I would like to separate this antislash from the rest of the string with `&nbsp;` . 
Actually the filter itself work but right the string " " as is in the page.

```
angular.module('ngMod', []).
filter('antislash', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if( input==null || input.length === 0 ){
      return null;
    }else{  
      return '&nbsp;/&nbsp;'; 
    }
  }
});
```

It displays in the page : `&nbsp;/&nbsp;`

Does exist an html filter or something equivalent ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It works by giving the [unicode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) value for `&nbsp;`.

```
angular.module('ngMod', []).
filter('antislash', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if( input==null || input.length === 0 ){
      return null;
    }else{  
      return '\u00A0/\u00A0'; 
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use [$sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize) with `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to output html snipets.