# &nbsp; in script is not getting compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, angular-filters

I have created an application in AngularJS with a drop down with space in option using a filter. The application is working fine but the `&nbsp;` which I have put for space is not getting compiled.

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0sy8rkh/)**

**html**

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in headers">{{value | space}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**script**

```
app.filter('space', function() {
  return function(text) {
       if(_.isUndefined(text.mainId))
       {
           console.log('entered mainId');
           return text.value;
       }
       else
       {
           console.log('entered');
           return '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+text.value;
       }
  };
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431125/angular-js-return-a-string-with-html-characters-like-nbsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by giving the [unicode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) value for `&nbsp;`.

```
app.filter('space', function() {
  return function(text) {
       if(_.isUndefined(text.mainId))
       {
           console.log('entered mainId');
           return text.value;
       }
       else
       {
           console.log('entered');
           return '\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0'+text.value;
       }
  };
```

[Answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431125/angular-js-return-a-string-with-html-characters-like-nbsp/12431145#12431145)

Comment: can we remove that space at the time of select

Comment: If you want to remove space when user selected it, You can capture event selected and send value of select

Comment: You can also use $sanitize with ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe to output html snipets.

Comment: what i said is like in the drop down list it should shows with space but when we select one there it should show any space in front

Answer (score 1):

Try like this `return '\u00A0' + text.value;`

Javascript doesn't know that you want to parse html entity, that's why we must use unicode code.

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0sy8rkh/2/)

Comment: can we remove that space at the time of select

Comment: you can try :)) theoreticaly it possible

Comment: what i said is like in the drop down list it should shows with space but when we select one there it should show any space in front