# javascript \u00Ao is not working

Tags: javascript

I have reference for using ;nbsp in javascript from [&nbsp; in script is not getting compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804718/nbsp-in-script-is-not-getting-compiled) but It still couldn't work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var addButtonn = $('.add_rescuer'); //Add button selector
    var wrapperr = $('.field_rescuer'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTMLL = '<div data-role="dynamic-fields"><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter"><label for="instansi"><font color="white">Instansi yang Terlibat:</font></label> \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rescuer[]" placeholder="Masukkan Kegiatan" required size="92"/></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_rescuer btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Hapus Kegiatan"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i></a></div></div></div>'; //New input field html 
    var y = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButtonn).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        y++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapperr).append(fieldHTMLL); // Add field html
    });
    $(wrapperr).on('click', '.remove_rescuer', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        y--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
```

When I tried to running that code, it was not changing anything. What is the problem ? \u00A0 has not worked properly.

Comment: Try this: `\ua0`

Comment: When I changed \u00A0 to \ua0, at the same time the other function is not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that font color is the problem, i think it's in white color: 
for your reference
https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/ybWxxW

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var addButtonn = $('.add_rescuer'); //Add button selector
   var wrapperr = $('.field_rescuer'); //Input field wrapper
   var fieldHTMLL = '<div data-role="dynamic-fields"><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter"><label for="instansi"><font color="black">Instansi yang Terlibat:</font></label> \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rescuer[]" placeholder="Masukkan Kegiatan" required size="92"/></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_rescuer btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Hapus Kegiatan"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i></a></div></div></div>'; //New input field html 
   var y = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
   $(addButtonn).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
     y++; //Increment field counter
     $(wrapperr).append(fieldHTMLL); // Add field html
   });
   $(wrapperr).on('click', '.remove_rescuer', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    y--; //Decrement field counter
   });
});
```